# Why is Spider silent?

Tags: stephen-mallatratt, the-woman-in-black

Sound is a major defining component of *The Woman in Black*: many of the imaginary and semi-present elements of the performance get explicit sound cues. They're a diegetic conceit of the framing device, and serve to make the pantomime more understandable.

So why is the dog Spider, who is entirely invisible and only given presence through the actors' pantomimed interactions, not given any sound effect cues at all? Even when the dialog narrates cues like "she is yelping loudly," the sound direction never backs it up.